# How can I create a subtitle in "list of figures" and "list of tables"?

Tags: table-of-contents

This time I have a little harder question...
It's not about making the captions and titles shorter. The appendixes figures and tables are labeled with letters (A1, A2... etc). So, I'd like to have inside list of tables and list of figures a SUBTITLE so the final layout looks like this:

5.6 Graph of concentrations bla bla bla ................ 56

Appendix A: (Title...)

A.1 Graph of functionality bla bla bla ................. 59

and same for list of tables (and appendix B which has the supplementary tables).

Since the list of tables and figures are generated automatically I cant find how to break into them to create these "subtitles"...

Thank you very much in advance!
Regards

```
\documentclass[a4paper,BCOR=6mm]{report}
\usepackage{typearea}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{futs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{anysize}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{svg}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand\fnote[1]{\captionsetup{font=small}\caption*{#1}}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,uniquename=init,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
\addbibresource{myref.bib}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs, array, longtable, ragged2e, pdflscape}

\title{Desde semillas nutritivas a alimentos complejos: Marcadores de estabilidad de componentes bioactivos a lo largo de la cadena de producción.}
\author{Licenciado en Química Federico Iván Brigante}
\date{today}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\input{Título}

\input{Abstracto}

\chapter*{Dedicatoria}
completar


\chapter*{Agradecimientos}
\begin{itemize}
    \item o
    \item j
    \item ok
    \item ok
    \item ok
    \item ok
    \item ok
    \item ok
    \item ok
\end{itemize}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Introducción general.}
\input{Introducción.tex}
\newpage
\chapter*{Objetivos}
\input{Objetivos.tex}
\chapter{this}
\input{C3.tex}
\chapter{that}
\input{C5.tex}
\chapter{Metabolómica dirigida por cromatografía líquida de alta resolución.}
\input{C2.tex}
\chapter{Desarrollo de alimentos funcionales con incorporación de harina de semillas de sésamo. Evaluación del efecto del procesado y la digestión gastro intestinal sobre sus características antioxidantes.}
\input{C10.tex}
\chapter{Conclusión general}
\input{Conclusión General.tex}

\appendix
\chapter{Cuadros suplementarios.}
\input{prueba}
\chapter{Figuras suplementarias.}
\input{figsup}
\chapter{Presentaciones y publicaciones.}
\input{Presypub}

\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem (and what yo have done to try and solve it). Have you looked at the `tocloft` package manual which discusses such things?

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer, how can I send you that MWE??? @PeterWilson Wilson

Comment: Hey @Fred21, click on `edit` underneath your question text (in this case, just underneath `table-of-contents`) and add in a small example of your code that shows the error or undesired behaviour. [This here demonstrates what a MWE involves](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/245306), hope it helps.

Comment: @LaccaseTVersicolor Hi! I added it, but in this case, there is not an error, its something I want to add and idk how... I've seen other posts about this but none has come up with a clear solution

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant by undesired behaviour i.e. there is no error but it is not producing what you desire. In the future, we do not have access to your `input` files e.g. `\input{C5.tex}` so we cannot compile your code. Somebody might be able to help just by looking at your code but it's helpful if the code can compile so solutions can be tried faster. Most of your packages can be removed too, for a MWE you should only include the packages that are important, `\usepackage{tablefootnote}` has little to do with the LOF or LOT. Thanks for including code, hope someone can help.